# Mobile-Friendly CSS - How to hide a sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an app ( http://infranodus.com ) which has a menu on the left and the main login form in the center. The rest of the space is used for a graph that is shown to users when they log into the site.

Does anybody know how I can make it so that when you open this same page in iOS

1) the left  menu is automatically hidden (which automatically happens now if you make the browser window more narrow)

2) the login form takes the size of the screen

Thank you!

UPDATE

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: google "media queries"

Comment: if your left menu already hides when the window gets narrower, then there is nothing more you need to do since iOS has a narrow window. You should also not target devices but the width of the page

Comment: What is happening when you load this page on iOs? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @SajithNair yes - there it is - and what I want is that when we open it in iOS we don't see the left-hand menu and the login form takes the whole window...

Comment: @Quentin why did you mark it as offtopic if that was a valid problem that was clearly resolved with the information there was available above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

[For more info check developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS media queries like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    #menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide sidebar in iOS with [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Example

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
.sidebar{
display:block;
}
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 280px) {
.sidebar{
display:none;
}
}
```